# React UI/dom is not updating after data insertion in json-server

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, single-page-application

I am learning React from few days and I am trying to learn Axios, Everything worked fine until I tried to insert data, which I successfully inserted but My React Page did not updated contact list immediately.

HERE's MY CODE:

App.js

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Add__Contact from "./api/Add__Contact";

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const url = "http://localhost:3006/contacts";

  //get all availbale contacts
  useEffect(() => {
    // get all contacts async
    async function getUsers() {
      Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setContacts(response.data);
      });
    }
    getUsers();

    console.log(contacts);

    // get all contacts non-async
    // Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    //     setContacts(response.data);
    // });
  }, []);

  //add new contact to server
  const addContact = () => {
    const saveRes = Add__Contact({ name, phone });
  };

  // view
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Add contact</h4>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="name here" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Phone here"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={addContact}>Add to Contact</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <h4>List of Contacts</h4>
      <div>
        {contacts.map((contact) => {
          return (
            <div key={contact.id}>
              <span>{contact.name} : </span>
              <span> {contact.phone}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Add__Contact.js

```
import Axios from "axios";

const Add__Contact = async ({ name, phone }) => {
  Axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3006/contacts",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: {
      name,
      phone,
    },
  }).then(function (res) {
    // console.log(res);
  });
};

export default Add__Contact;
```

db.json

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Max",
      "phone": "123456",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "phone": "13454",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Candy",
      "phone": "1245781245",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure why it's not updating list automatically, I thought `useEffect` will run everytime I click and call `Add__Contact()`. Can you please tell me what did i missed or doing wrong?

I am not sure if `useEffect` hook is good for what I want to achieve or not, so please guide me. Thank you in advance.
data insertion is working fine, but after I insert it, it's not updating ui, even if I am fetching data inside useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook is only ran once - when the component mounts. This is because you have given it an empty dependency array (the 2nd argument).

The dependency array determines when the effect function will run. If its empty, it will only run when the component is mounted (displayed for the very first time). If you add something in the array, the effect will run on mount, and whenever the provided value changes.

In your case, you have an event (the click event from the Add to Contacts button) after which you want your data to be fetched again. But you also want to fetch data when the page loads.

One way to do it is something like this:

```
const Add__Contact = async ({ name, phone }) => {
  // Return the Promise returned from the Axios call
  return Axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3006/contacts",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: {
      name,
      phone,
    },
  });
};

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const url = "http://localhost:3006/contacts";

  // Add a function to fetch contacts
  const fetchContacts = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(url);
    setContacts(res.data);
  };

  // Effect that fetches contacts when the component loads
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContacts();
  }, []);

  //add new contact to server
  const addContact = async () => {
    // await the Promise returned
    const saveRes = await Add__Contact({ name, phone });

    // Fetch the contacts list again
    await fetchContacts();
  };

  // view
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Add contact</h4>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="name here" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Phone here"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={addContact}>Add to Contact</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <h4>List of Contacts</h4>
      <div>
        {contacts.map((contact) => {
          return (
            <div key={contact.id}>
              <span>{contact.name} : </span>
              <span> {contact.phone}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This one worked like charm, calling `fetchData()` do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

So you'r **Contacts** Array is not updated .Even you got a data from axios call .

Like if axios is returning data then i think you'r state in not updating  then you have to use

```
setContacts((prv)=>[...prv,...res.data])
```

If you'r facing problem on Add time . Then make a separate function then use that in useEffect() && your ADD_Contact() .

```
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const getContacts = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:3006/contacts');
    setContacts(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getContacts();
  }, []);

  const addContact = async () => {
    const saveRes = await Add__Contact({ name, phone });
    await getContacts();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Add contact</h4>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="name here" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Phone here"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={addContact}>Add to Contact</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <h4>List of Contacts</h4>
      <div>
        {contacts.map((contact) => {
          return (
            <div key={contact.id}>
              <span>{contact.name} : </span>
              <span> {contact.phone}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: if i use `setContacts((prv)=>[...prv,...res.data])` it is updating but showing Two times entries, like: ``Max : 123456
John : 13454
Candy : 1245781245
jits : 56858745
kish : 12313
abcd : 546546
123 : 21313
dsfdfd : 454353
gfdgdfg : 564645
Max : 123456
John : 13454
Candy : 1245781245
jits : 56858745
kish : 12313
abcd : 546546
123 : 21313
dsfdfd : 454353
gfdgdfg : 564645

Comment: also previously if I refresh all contacts were showing, but not automaticlly(without refresh) , i had to refresh manually to see latest list.

Comment: setContacts((prv)=>[...res.data]) Can you please check using this way

Comment: manually refreshing case happened because you need to update your state when you add something new . you have to call you method again to get a fresh data.

Comment: `setContacts((prv)=>[...res.data])` is also not working. @ali Nauman 's code(trick) worked